# Read health data using "Health Connect" API (android java app)

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, health-monitoring, healthconnect

I am currently working on developing a health app and I would like to be able to read and display health data information (already stored through the phone/smart watch sensors) using the Health Connect SDK.
Some tutorials are available (https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/get-started    https://developer.android.com/codelabs/health-connect#0) but unfortunately they are in Kotlin and I am coding my app in Java language. Are there any other resources that could help me with Java instead ?

I am struggling with the ReadRecordsRequest ( https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/health/connect/client/request/ReadRecordsRequest ) and ReadRecords ( https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/health/connect/client/HealthConnectClient#readRecords(androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest) ) methods as I tried to unsuccesfully initialise their input paramerter (T in my case) but it's not the correct type...

Here is a portion of my code :

```
androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest<T> request = new androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest<T>(
                        TimeRangeFilter.between(start,end),
                        emptySet(),
                        false,
                        1000,
                        null
                );

                // Call the readRecords method on the HealthConnectClient
                Continuation<? super ReadRecordsResponse<T>> cont = new Continuation<T>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void resumeWith(@NonNull Object o) {

                    }
                };
                List<Record> response = healthConnectClient.readRecords(request,cont);
                return filterOxygenRecords(response);
```

These are the errors I get :
'readRecords(androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super androidx.health.connect.client.response.ReadRecordsResponse>)' in 'androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient' cannot be applied to '(androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<capture<? super ReadRecordsResponse>>)'

Unknown class: 'T'

[Picture of the Expected required type vs required one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m03KF.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To convert this code in java you need to change syntax and for `suspend` function use AsyncTask for java

Comment: I tried to convert this code in Java and I am currently struggling with the initialisation of the ReadRecordsRequest and ReadRecords methods in Java.
This is the error I get : 'readRecords(androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest<T>, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super androidx.health.connect.client.response.ReadRecordsResponse<T>>)' in 'androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient' cannot be applied to '(androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest<T>, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<capture<? super ReadRecordsResponse<T>>>)'

Comment: Update: Hello, I would like to know how to initialize ReadRecordsRequest ReadRecordsResponse ReadRecords instances with the correct input parameters types. Android studio suggest some types that I can succesfully use, for example how can I convert it to a KClass, knowing that KClass is a Kotlin feature ? Are these methods compatible with Java code ?

Comment: here my friend: https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health/blob/master/src/android/HealthPlugin.java

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend you to do is to configure your project such that you only have Health Connect specific code in Kotlin. That way you, don't need to refactor your project in its entirety.

```
  <T extends Record>
```

"T" here implies the use of Generics.